# Dynamically loading x & y coordinates from text file into html page as pixels for some points locations

Tags: javascript, python, html, database, maps

I need to get a web page for the map of an area.
I am trying to do it with just having the image of the map for that area loaded onto the web page, locate the points just as you can see in my attached png-file and do more as I prefer with it.

Assuming there are basically 6 stations in that area as shown in the text file below,

```python
#
# some sensor network
#
SN.field_x = 5000 
SN.field_y = 2000
SN.numNodes = 6
# Name: station1 type: antenna1
SN.node[0].xCoor = 1000
SN.node[0].yCoor = 800 
# Name: station2 type: antenna1
SN.node[1].xCoor = 2000 
SN.node[1].yCoor = 808 
# Name: station3 type: antenna2
SN.node[2].xCoor = 1800
SN.node[2].yCoor = 743 
# Name: station4 type: antenna2
SN.node[3].xCoor = 2061
SN.node[3].yCoor = 747 
# Name: station5 type: antenna3
SN.node[4].xCoor = 2325
SN.node[4].yCoor = 753
# Name: station6 type: antenna3
SN.node[5].xCoor = 1689
SN.node[5].yCoor = 681
```

I need to show these stations on the map with correct positioning based on the coordinate data from that text file.
I have to locate each of those points on the map(which is an image) based on those x & y coordinates. I tried to do this by hard-coding the x & y coord into the css script as pixels which gives me the page in that picture attached. But I need to get it loaded dynamically because those stations might be re-positioned in the future. Someone told me that I can use python which I have no idea how it works. Please I need your help on how I can go about this. Thanks.

[image: stationMap]

**My HTML & CSS now added below**

The left and top pixel values are based on the x & y coord from the text file

```
<head>
<title>MAP</title>
<style type="text/css">
#menu{width:2997px;height:1471px;background-image:url(Map.png)}
#menu a{position:absolute;height:10px;width:10px;}
a#a1{left:974.1px;top:409.3px;border:solid 2px #0099cc} 
a#a2{left:1096.3px;top:404.1px;border:solid 2px #0099cc}
a#a3{left:901.7px;top:371.9px;border:solid 2px #0099cc} 
a#a4{left:1030.7px;top:373.9px;border:solid 2px #0099cc}
a#a5{left:1162.8px;top:376.3px;border:solid 2px #0099cc} 
a#a6{left:844.8px;top:340.7px;border:solid 2px #0099cc}

#menu a i{ visibility:hidden;}
</style></head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
<a id="a1"href="#"><i>Link 1</i></a>
<a id="a2"href="#"><i>Link 2</i></a>
<a id="a3"href="#"><i>Link 3</i></a>
<a id="a4"href="#"><i>Link 4</i></a>
<a id="a5"href="#"><i>Link 5</i></a>
<a id="a6"href="#"><i>Link 6</i></a>
</div></body>
```

Comment: Could you please show your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Load it dynamically from what?

Comment: you can use python as a cgi-script to print out your css

Comment: @Asad HTML and CSS file added. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric I want to load the from a file containing x and y coord of those stations.

Comment: @User thanks for pointing out that but I am new to python, could you please give any links on similar project.

Comment: Is the number of stations variable as well? Does your file have to be in that format?

Comment: @Eric The total number of stations are already known but just their positions that might change. I think the file will be in that format because someone else is working on that, that is why I need to make dynamic on my side incase the values change on his side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now I figured something out.. please have a look wether it is useful: (python script)

```
from collections import defaultdict # a mapping for station number to points

class Point(object):
    # der punkt mit xCoor yCoor
    pass

class SN:
    # the SN object in text file
    node = defaultdict(Point)

# read the text file
textFileContent = open('IDoNotKnowYourTextFileName.txt').read()

# in the next line you need to trust the other person - it executes the textfile 
# but only knowing SN
exec textFileContent in {'SN': SN}

# in the following lines you can output the html file you need:
print '''<head>
<title>MAP</title>
<style type="text/css">
#menu{width:2997px;height:1471px;background-image:url(Map.png)}
#menu a{position:absolute;height:10px;width:10px;}'''

for stationNumber, stationPoint in SN.node.items():
    x = stationPoint.xCoor
    y = stationPoint.yCoor
    # sorry, but I could not get how you derive the x,y-positions from yout html
    print 'a#a' + str(stationNumber) + '{left:' + str(x) + 'px;top:' + str(y) + 'px;border:solid 2px #0099cc}'

print '''
#menu a i{ visibility:hidden;}
</style></head>
<body>
<div id="menu">'''
```

Comment: I have been working on this and its been giving some expected result but it seems that stationNumber in that for loop is making the script to stop print. When I remove that stationNumber it prints every other thing else. But I guess the stationNumber is to print like(station1, station2, ..., station6). Please help me look into it as I have not been able to resolve it. Thank you so much for this help.

Comment: I had a misspelling: 'staionNumber' != 'stationNumber'

Comment: Thanks so much, I had earlier changed the 'stationNumber' to 'Name' and it generated the numbers(0,1,2,...,5) just as the correctly written 'stationNumber' now does. I am just thinking if its possible to get the name of each station out like(station1, station2,...,staion5) as it is in the text file and to replace those numbers(0,1,...,5) that are being generated now. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in Javascript using CSS3 and the Canvas. The other way to do it is you could actually make a new image with python through way of a CGI script or something similar, small django application for instance. That would produce your image for you so it would be called similarly like:

```
<img src="http://some-domain.com/cgi/get_coorinates_on_image.py?file=the_test.txt">
```

And it would return a properly formatted image or you can return CSS file as suggested or use javascript to do a ajax call to a cgi or django instance to get a json of the positions and then you can use javascript to position the locations on the image.

EDIT:

PIL, it's outdate but easy to use and is perfect for your situation.

http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Django, works pretty well comes with a basic built in HTTP server and a lot of tutorials.

https://www.djangoproject.com/

CSS3 and Canvas

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation, and I will also appreciate if you can direct me to any link or tutorial on similar topic as I am new to python.

Comment: Thanks for those links, I have started checking them.